# MQ Connection - 2009 error

Tags: connection, ibm-mq

am connectting the MQ with below code. I am able connected to MQ successfully. My case is i place the messages to MQ every 1 min once. After disconnecting the cable i get a ResonCode error but IsConnected property still show true. Is this is the right way to check if the connection is still connected ? Or there any best pratcices around that.

I would like to open the connection when applicaiton is started keep it open for ever.

public static MQQueueManager ConnectMQ() 
{

if ((queueManager == null) || (!queueManager.IsConnected)||(queueManager.ReasonCode == 2009)) 
{ 
queueManager = new MQQueueManager(); 
} 
return queueManager; 
}

Answer (score 2):

The behavior of the WMQ client connection is that when idle it will appear to be connected until an API call fails or the connection times out.  So isConnected() will likely report true until a get, put or inquire call is attempted and fails, at which point QMgr will then report disconnected.

The other thing to consider here is that 2009 is not the only code you might get.  It happens to be the one you get when the connection is severed but there are connection codes for QMgr shutting down, channel shutting down, and a variety of resource and other errors.

Typically for a requirement to maintain a constant connection you would want to wrap the connect and message processing loop inside a try/catch block nested inside a while statement.  When you catch an exception other than an intentional exit, close the objects and QMgr, sleep at least 5 seconds, then loop around to the top of the while.  The sleep is crucial because if you get caught in a tight reconnect loop and throw hundreds of connection attempts at the QMgr, you can bring even a mainframe QMgr to its knees.

An alternative is to use a v7 WMQ client and QMgr.  With this combination, automatic reconnection is configurable as a channel configuration.